# Screenshot not being saved on mobile Device for Unity

Tags: unity, screenshot

I tried to save screenshots in Unity for mobile whenever some object appeared on the screen. It works completely fine when I run it in an emulator and also saves images. But when I run in the real device it does not save it.

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + "_coin_" + gameObject.name + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".png");
```

I have even set permission for accessing storage in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```